# Scala Array is subtype of Sequence

Tags: scala

How seq is accepting Array parameter input doPrint function.

```
def doPrint(x : Seq[Any]) : Unit ={
   x.foreach(println)
}

doPrint(List(1,32,4))
doPrint(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

List is subtype Seq , Not Array.How it is working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's thanks to an implicit conversion to a `WrappedArray`.

From [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_38.html) (many examples there):

> Scala 2.8 array implementation makes systematic use of implicit
>   conversions. In Scala 2.8 an array does not pretend to be a sequence.
>   It can't really be that because the data type representation of a
>   native array is not a subtype of Seq. Instead there is an implicit
>   "wrapping" conversion between arrays and instances of class
>   scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray, which is a subclass of Seq.

Answer (score 1):

Two implicit conversions exists for Array: **scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps** and **scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray**.

In case of 2nd method call, **Array** is implicitly converted to **WrappedArray** which is subtype of **Seq**.